# Looping two inputs until the user has finished entering

Tags: java, jgrasp

I'm trying to loop these two questions("please enter direction") AND ("Please enter distance in miles"). If incorrect value is inputed then it will reprompt the user to enter a correct value. So these two questions will loop until the user is done entering and a "Destination" is reached. I got the first question to loop if the user doesn't type north east south or west, but the second question I could only make it loop on itself.

```
boolean reprompt = true;
//Prompt for direction and miles

while (reprompt) {

   directions = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a direction: ");
   if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("East")) {
      finalxCoord = finalxCoord + numOfMiles;
      reprompt = false;
      }
      else if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("West")) {
               finalxCoord = finalxCoord - numOfMiles;
               reprompt = false;
               }
             else if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("North")) {
                     finalyCoord = finalyCoord + numOfMiles;
                     reprompt = false;
                     }
                     else if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("South")) {
                             finalyCoord = finalyCoord - numOfMiles;
                             reprompt = false;
                             }
             else {
                 reprompt = true;
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
             }    
        }

   numOfMiles = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter distance in miles: "));
   if (numOfMiles > 0) {
   totalMiles += numOfMiles;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "miles: " + totalMiles);


   }
   else 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the second question inside a while loop with another boolean just as you did for the first question. 
Code:

```
boolean restart = true;
//Prompt for direction and miles
while(restart){    

boolean reprompt = true;
boolean reprompt_SecondQuestion=true;

while (reprompt) {

   directions = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a direction: ");
   if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("East")) {
      finalxCoord = finalxCoord + numOfMiles;
      reprompt = false;
      }
      else if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("West")) {
               finalxCoord = finalxCoord - numOfMiles;
               reprompt = false;
               }
             else if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("North")) {
                     finalyCoord = finalyCoord + numOfMiles;
                     reprompt = false;
                     }
                     else if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("South")) {
                             finalyCoord = finalyCoord - numOfMiles;
                             reprompt = false;
                             }
             else {
                 reprompt = true;
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
             }    
        }
   while(reprompt_SecondQuestion)
   {
        numOfMiles = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter distance in miles: "));
        if (numOfMiles > 0) {
        totalMiles += numOfMiles;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "miles: " + totalMiles);
        reprompt_SecondQuestion = false;
   }
   else 
   {

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
   }
  }

    //Prompt user to type "done"
    //Capture user input
    if(user_input.equals("Done"))
    {
       //Display direction and miles to user
       restart = false;
    }
    else
    {
    }
  }
```

Comment: after two correct values are input, The program would ask if it's the final destination. If it's not the user will be asked again for a direction and distance in miles.

Comment: Please also add your code for your program asking for destination.

Comment: destination based on the prompts directions and numOfMiles. These two need to loop.

Comment: They will end once the user types "done" and a message output will show total miles and last direction(ex: "north" "east" "south" "or "west")

Comment: Alright that makes sense. I tried this, but after pressing ok to "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "miles: " + totalMiles);" It doesn't give me a input dialog for directions, but it says the program is still running.

Comment: YES! that worked! thanks! I believe I should move (user_inputs("done")) under the directions statement and add else if (directions.equals("done")). I could use break; to end loop and have a showmessagedialog output directions and totalMiles at the end of the code. 

Edit: wait no it'll still go to the next loop.

Comment: You are welcome :) I think break will only end the loop for else if. You can experiment. If you have any questions, you can open another question.